# Ember.js - how to force loading of related objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js, has-many

I have two models

```js
App.Poll = DS.Model.extend({
    id:         DS.attr('string'),
    title:      DS.attr('string'),
    answers:    DS.hasMany('App.Answer')
});

App.Answer = DS.Model.extend({
    id:         DS.attr('string'),
    value:      DS.attr('number')
});

App.Poll.FIXTURES = [{
    id:         '1',
    title:      'PollTitle',
    answers:    ['3', '4']
}];

App.Answer.FIXTURES = [{
    id:         '3',
    value:      1
},{
    id:         '4',
    value:      2
}];

App.PollsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.Poll.find('1');
    }
});
```

I created helper, which counts value of specified field in array of models

```js
Ember.Handlebars.helper('fieldSum', function(arr, ops){
    var res = 0;

    arr.forEach(function(item){
        res += item.get(ops.hash.field);
    });

    return new Handlebars.SafeString(res);
});
```

```html
<div class="count">{{fieldSum answers field="value"}}</div>
```

But in helper body I got empty (not loaded) `answers`, only `id` fileds, so I can't count their values and result of this helper is NaN

But after `{{#each answers}}` all answers are loaded.

Can I somehow force loading of related objects in `App.PollsRoute` or in my helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper
```

instead of:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper
```

Comment: `helper` is equivalent to `registerBoundHelper`

Comment: if you go to the documentation for helper http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/ you'll find a section called "DEPENDENCIES", there, you can find how to observe for property changes, and if you go to http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_registerBoundHelper you'll find that you are not required to do that

Comment: But also in `App.AnswersRoute` I had to do this `var poll = App.Poll.find('1'); poll.get('store').findMany(App.Answer, ['3','4']); return poll;`